# Pick a list of values from one CSV and get the count of the values of the list in a different CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i am working on python code to calculate the occurrences of few values in a column within a CSV.

Example - CSV1 is as below

```
**Type  Value**
Simple  test
complex problem
simple  formula
complex theory
simple  idea
simple  task
```

I need to get the content of value for type simple and complex i.e

```
**Type    Value**
simple  test
simple  formula
simple  idea
simple  task

complex theory
complex problem
```

And query other CSV which is CSV1 on the total count of occurrences of `simple list i.e [test, formula, idea, task] and complex list i.e [theory, problem]`

Other CSV2 is

```
**Category**
test
test
test
formula
formula
formula
test
test
idea
task
task
idea
task
idea
task
problem
problem
theory
problem
problem
idea
task
problem
test
```

Both CSV1 and CSV2 are dynamic, from CSV1 as example for type "simple' get the list of the corresponding values and refer CSV2 to know what's count for each value. i.e counts of test, idea, task, formula.

Same for Complex type
I tried multiple methods with pandas but not expecting result as expected. Any pointers please.

Comment: `And query other CSV on the total count of occurrences` - it means merge another DataFrame an count? Is possible add another data to question and add expected ouput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df2['cat'] = df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Value')['Type'])

df2 = df2['cat'].value_counts().rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df2)
         a   b
0   simple  18
1  complex   6
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, but i did not get this working. I have edited my question could you please help to review once

Comment: @goe - Ok, but mybe you forget add expected ouput from both csv.

Comment: ouput is total count of values for type simple, and total count of values for type complex from CSV2

Comment: @goe - I think how exactly looks final DataFrame.

Comment: @goe - I try guess and edited answer, but not sure if need this or soemthing else.

Comment: i tried `import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ("csv1.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv ("csv2.csv")
df = df.sort_values('Type', ascending=False)
df = (df1.merge(df1, on='Value', how='left').groupby(['Type','Value'])
         .size().reset_index(name='count'))'  i am getting error as 'Key Error Type`

Comment: @goe - So it means columnsnames are different like in question?

Comment: CSV1 - Column names Type and Value, and CSV 2 Column is Category these are column names.

Comment: So it is different like in question? Not understand why is not added expected ouput? Guessing answers is not easy :(

Comment: I sincerely apologize for confusion, i was unable to articulate properly. Corrected the question now...Sorry again and Thank you for your support.

Comment: @goe - One thing - Try imagine you need ask something to very busy person in work. So need prepar the best as possible. In SO working this same way - if create bad question, get some guessing answers or nothing (only downvotes). Maybe help you [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230130/discussion-between-goe-and-jezrael).

Comment: I am not sure if I did something wrong, not able to figure out this code `import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv ("csv1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv ("csv2.csv")
#print(df1)
#print(df2)
df2['cat'] = df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Value')['Type'])
df2 = df2['cat'].value_counts().rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df2)` Error as `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: @goe it means there are duplicates,  need `import pandas as pd df1 = pd.read_csv ("csv1.csv") df2 = pd.read_csv ("csv2.csv") #print(df1) #print(df2) df1=df1.drop_duplicates('Value') df2['cat'] = df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Value')['Type']) df2 = df2['cat'].value_counts().rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b') print (df2)`

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: when I ran above I get empty dataframe `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []'

Comment: The data will have duplicates, so removing might fail. But i was wondering at one point of time it did work. Not sure why its failing now.

Comment: @goe I think is necessary do research and find data which failed. If working in this data and not in real data it is real data problem. So need filtwr firs 10, 20, 50, n rows and find where data failed and then looking for problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Much like @jezrael,however I would first groupby the second csv. This would help in merging if the second csv is very large.

```
df2=cv2.groupby('value').agg(cnt=('value','count')).reset_index()
```

This would give me a dataframe with two columns, value and count.

Now, you can merge it with CV1

```
df1 = cv1.merge(df2,on=['value'],how='inner')
```